# Billing Library - Testing InApp subscriptions of different countries/regions

Tags: android, android-emulator, location, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using Google Play Billing library system to make subscriptions inside my app. I am trying to do in-app purchase from my application on an Android Emulator device from a particular region

Now., i would like to test the working of the same InApp Purchase subscriptions of a different country/region from my application. Is it possible to change location in order to test the InApp purchases of that particular country/region . If so, can you please suggest on how to change the location and then test the InApp Purchases from my application?